# Use of Binomial Distribution in question on the diameter of trees

Tags: r, self-study

Suppose that the diameter of trees of a certain type are normally distributed with $\mu = 8.8in $ and $\sigma = 1.75in$ If four trees are independently selected, what is the probability that at least one tree has a diameter exceeding than $10in$?

$X\sim{N(8.8,1.75^2)}$

So the probability for a single tree's diameter being greater than 10 is:

$P(X\ge 10) = 1 - P(X<10)$

Standardize: $ z=\frac{10-8.8}{2.8} = 0.43$

$1 - P(z<0.43) =$ `1 - pnorm(0.43) = 0.334`

If $n = 4$ independent trees, then if I was to create a new distribution $Y$ with a diameter greater than 10, then $Y\sim binom(4,.334)$ I can conclude that:

$P(Y \ge 1) = 1 - P(Y \le 0) =$ `1-dbinom(0,4,.334) = 0.803`

Is this correct? Would it make sense that this can be considered to be a binomial distribution? Under what conditions should I use `dbinom` over `pbinom` commands?

Comment: This appears to be a homework question, so please add the self-study tag.

Comment: This is a minor point, but since the diameter of a tree cannot be <0, the diameters cannot be normally distributed.

Comment: If the standard deviation is 1.75 as indicated, then the standardized value should be `(standardized <- (10 - 8.8)/1.75)   0.6857143`. Then, `pnorm(10, 8.8, 1.75, lower.tail = F) = 0.2464466` getting the same result with `1- pnorm(standardized)` or `pnorm(standardized, lower.tail = F)`.